# how to config to make less works with React?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, less

It's a new project created with react CLI.
what I have done :

1. first, run `npm run eject`
2. run `npm i less less-loader`
3. modify webpack.config:

```
const cssRegex = /\.(css|less)$/;
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.(css|less)$/;

 // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
            // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
            // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
            // In production, we use MiniCSSExtractPlugin to extract that CSS
            // to a file, but in development "style" loader enables hot editing
            // of CSS.
            // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 2,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction
                  ? shouldUseSourceMap
                  : isEnvDevelopment,
                  modules: true, 
              },'less-loader'),
              // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
              // containing package claims to have no side effects.
              // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
              // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
              sideEffects: true,
            },
```

4. npm start
   and I got an error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-4-3!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-4!./src/index.css)
TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function
```

did I miss something?

Comment: http://redino.net/blog/2021/04/syntax-error-typeerror-this-getoptions-is-not-a-function/ might help here

Comment: oh... it works for me, although I don't know why